# Laravel inspector class not found error

Tags: php, class, laravel-4

I am getting error on Laravel 4.

Here is the error details

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Whoops\Exception\Inspector' not found in /home/igidonli/public_html/meeting/vendor/filp/whoops/src/Whoops/Run.php on line 95

Only one page gives this error, other pages working well

I googled but I can't found anyting.

```
    public function showStep()
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, 'tr_TR');
        $this->initTimes();
        $this->calculateTotalMeetingCount();

        $time = $this->getStepByTime();
        if ($time['step']==1) return $this->step1($time);
        if ($time['step']==2) return $this->step2($time);
    }

    private function step1($time){

        $step = View::make('layout/step')
            ->with('meetingDate',strftime('%e %B %Y',$this->meetingDate))
            ->with('stepTime',strftime('%e %B %Y',$time['time']));

        $sectors = new Sectors;
        $sectorsList = $sectors->getSectors();

        $firms = new Firms;
        $involvedFirms = $firms->InvolvedList(Request::get('sektor'))->get();

        $requests = new Requests;
        $requestedFirms = $requests->RequestsByFirmID(Auth::user()->id);
        $requestCount = $requests->RequstCount(Auth::user()->id);

        $content = View::make('step'.$time['step'])
            ->with('firmsList',$involvedFirms)
            ->with('requests',$requestedFirms)
            ->with('totalMeeting',$this->meetingCount)
            ->with('sectorList',$sectorsList)
            ->with('reqCount',$requestCount);
        $step->content = $content;
        $this->layout->content = $content;
    }
```

Layout/step.blade.php

```
<div class="jumbotron banner mini">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="welcome">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <i><div><strong>{{ $stepTime }}</strong></div><div class="date-desc">tarihine kadar randevu listenizi düzenleyiniz.</div></i>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-7  hidden-sm hidden-xs text-center pull-right">
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tip">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 date">
                    İGİD İkili Görüşmeler  - {{ $meetingDate }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    SWISSOTEL BUYUK EFES, IZMIR
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{ $content }}
```

Laravel gives blank page.
I saw error in error.log

Comment: What is the pages code (controller, model, etc.)? You have to give us more to work with than just the error message.

Comment: @MitchGlenn I added code block. Before this block code works well

Comment: You're only giving me a tiny piece to work off, what are your routes? I'm assuming this is your controller. What about the view `layout/step`?

Comment: I don't know if slashes works for template directories as I didn't try but a period `.` can

Comment: @MitchGlenn I added codes.

Comment: @revo I also tried with dot. And code works on local. I am getting error on server

Comment: You aren't returning the `View::make('layout/step')` try, `$step = return View::make('layout/step')...`

Comment: Same with `$content = View::make()` you need to return the view, so `$content = return View::make()...`

Comment: Will error disappear on commenting out template related parts of code?

Comment: Code works on local. And return View::make() is returning result to function

Comment: @revo no. Only blank page. I can see errors in error.log

Comment: It just seems that the file is missing. Have you tried `composer update`? Or even deleting whole composer folder and installing it again?

Comment: @Raphael_25 I have tried clean install, composer update, upload from local. Nothing changed

Comment: We don't know about the methods used here, you'd better remove all your `step1` or the earlier called function and try to trace the lines one by one. It's awful but has many chances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

changing

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'tr_TR');
```

to

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'tr_TR');
```

Now it works!